Clickhouse on Mac: server configuration
I can't connect to clickhouse server on Mac.
I downloaded the binary via: curl https://clickhouse.com/ | sh.
I can then run ./clickhouse server.  This creates files in the working directory, including a directory of preprocessed_configs.  Nowhere is a users.xml file created.
The docs say I can run ./clickhouse client but it gives the error:
ClickHouse client version 24.4.1.1733 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Code: 516. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect, or there is no user with such name.

If you have installed ClickHouse and forgot password you can reset it in the configuration file.
The password for default user is typically located at /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml
and deleting this file will reset the password.
See also /etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml on the server where ClickHouse is installed.

. (AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)

It mentions /etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml but nothing exists there.  Also, my /etc folder has very little in it.  It feels like Mac does not use this dir as commonly as linux.
Where do I put the configuration, including users.xml?

This seems like a bug or some other issue. I just ran that curl command on my mac to download the latest binary, ran "./clickhouser server" then "./clickhouse client" in a new terminal - and it worked fine OOTB.

I created a config dir in /etc/clickhouse-server, like it mentioned.  This dir was definitely created for me on linux. Not sure how I installed it on that box but it was easier than on Mac.
I put this config.xml there and users.xml. I also had to create dirs in /var/lib/clickhouse-server and /var/log/clickhouse-server, too, and change their owner.
In users.xml I put the password 'qwe' and started the server: ./clickhouse server -C /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml.
In a separate terminal: ./clickhouse client --password pwe.
